# In Windows cmd, how to replace the " special character with a line break?

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

Just to be thorough, I'll state here my whole project and what I'm aiming at.

I intend to adapt a shell script to work in Windows cmd, as this is intended for people who are not going to have some sophisticate language available.

```
for g in $(curl -Ls https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/archives | jq -rc ".archives[]") ; do curl -Ls "$g" | jq -rc ".games[].pgn" ; done >> games.pgn
```

For some reason, Chess.com's API doesn't have a very important feature that Lichess' does, to export all games of a single player, so what I can do manually is to use `https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/archives` to export all available monthly archives and then hit the API for each one of them. (`hikaru` inside this will be a set variable, it's the nickname of the desired player to export).

The result for this command is something like

```
{"archives":["https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2015/11","https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2015/12","https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/02","https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/03","https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/04","https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/05"]}
```

to which I only have to append `/pgn` to get the desired result.

Obviously, cmd doesn't have `jq` available, so this involves "parsing" the string inside a batch file.

I figured if I just could replace every occurrence of `"` with a linebreak and echo the results, I could then use `find` (or `findstr`) to easily get a list of lines that only would need to be prefaced with `curl`  and appended with `/pgn` to get my final result.

The big question is: how do I replace `"` with a linebreak in cmd? I found a few answers, but none of them seems to work with a special character, part of the problem is that I also didn't understand these answers enough to try and adapt them.

A second way of perhaps achieving the same result would be replacing `[`, `]` and `,` with line breaks, but then I would also have to worry with deleting the final `"` to append `/pgn`, so if I'm able to do the former, it would be cleaner.

Comment: What you should do, is use something which is designed to parse that type of data, instead of trying to use batch files, which were designed to run a series of simple commands. Windows has PowerShell, which is infinitely more capable, and has built in functionality for JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your own answer, it seems as if you could remove at least one of those steps by using the brackets `[` and `]`, as delimiters.

You could also nest a for loop within another instead of having individual ones and writing to files.

Here it is as a single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
@(For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%G In ("input.txt") Do @For %%H In (%%G) Do @Echo curl.exe "%%~H/pgn") 1>"list.txt"
```

To do it directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```sh
(For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %G In ("input.txt") Do @For %H In (%G) Do @Echo curl.exe "%~H/pgn") 1>"list.txt"
```

Comment: This seems it would work, except the pgn chess format uses brackets, so I think more passes are needed in order the delims are not applied after the curl command gives it's output. Nevertheless, this is a very good answer and I will study it over the next few days to improve what I already have!

Comment: I did test and it did output the results I informed you, but perhaps my phrasing was wrong. I mean it theoretically seemed to work, but not in practice. The issue presented was beyond the scope of this question, that's why I didn't go into further details. Also, please keep in mind your answer came after I posted mine, indicating the problem was solved. The only reason I didn't accept it yet was for the minimum time to wait before accepting my own answer. I also intended to edit it with knowledge gained from your answer, but as I said, it wound be beyond the scope, so I'll end it now.

Comment: The task was provided in your question, you gave an example and told us what you wanted, i.e. `{"STRING":["URI","URI","URI","URI","URI","URI"]}`, intended results were each of the URI's suffixed with `/pgn` on separate lines. That is what my answer does. You haven't made clear to me what exactly is failing with my code, either in your question, or the above comments, but if there are characters in them which are not normal in a URI, and you haven't told us what those are, I'm struggling to work out how you answer can work when mine cannot. Please provide me with the missing information I need!

Comment: Sure, this is what happens: the final task I intended to do was to run multiple curl commands that look like `https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2015/11/pgn` (I have barely mentioned it when I wrote about "appending `/pgn` to my output). This command outputs a specific kind of string, a [PGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation#Example), which can only be useful by redirecting the output to `file.pgn`. It turns out that pgns have lots of brackets, as you can see in the provided example, therefore I'll need to study carefully when `delims=[]` is active or not.

Comment: Playing games? Perhaps you dislike the fact that I only presented you the exact same courtesy you showed me from the start. I never asked for someone to do the whole job for me, I had an issue with my code and I was trying to learn how to fix it. But here are the instructions to show how your code doesn't work and mine does (I'll even update my answer with a newer version to make it easier): run `curl https://api.chess.com/pub/player/fabiorzfreitas/games/archives>input.txt`, feed it to your code. Run my script, input nothing for lichess nickname, input `fabiorzfreitas` when asked, compare both

Comment: @Fabio, I've removed my last comment, because you seem to have thought it rude, and that was unintended. I've adjusted my code above to just output the results to list.txt, in exactly the same way as your initial answer does. If you take my code and you initial answer, and run them against the same input.txt file, my list.txt will contain a sequence of the same lines as yours, only with correctly used extension for cURL, and with the URI's doublequoted for safety. Mine will not leave an echo.txt or a replaced.txt, it is faster, and more robust. I didn't do the job for you, I fixed your answer.

Comment: Thanks, good thing we are on the same page again. I'll accept your answer, as it's better than mine, although I intend to update mine after I fully incorporate your code into my project, which means including the execution of the curl commands that generate `input.txt` and contained in `list.txt`

Comment: BTW, you need to fix you "single line batch file" part, it has double code, which does not match the code below.

Answer (score 1):

in batch/cmd, a `for` loop is used to process a list (separated by default delimiters like space, tab, comma). So just replace `[` and `]` with a space or comma, and you have a nice list to split. Finally, use `find` to filter the output to the relevant parts and you're done:

```
@Echo off
setlocal

set "string={"archives":["https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2015/11","https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2015/12","https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/02","https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/03","https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/04","https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/05"]}"


set "string=%string:[= %"
set "string=%string:]= %"
for %%a in (%string%) do echo %%~a|find "/"
```

Output:

```
https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2015/11
https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2015/12
https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/02
https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/03
https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/04
https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/games/2016/05
```

(in case you wonder: the tilde in `echo %%~a` removes surrounding quotes)

Comment: This is very close to what I need, except sometimes my input will be bigger than the max size for a set variable. I think I need to do the same, but using `for /f`. I'm trying with `for /f "tokens=* delims=,[]" %%a in (a.txt) do echo %%a`, but this just prints the whole line once. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I just worked with the string you gave. If you want to process a file, surround the code snippet with a `for /f` loop (like you did in your answer). But be aware - that also only works if *each line* is within the max size limit you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan's answer gave me the directions I needed to research more and build my own solution. This is not the final script to my project, but it does solve every problem presented in my original question:

```
@echo off
setLocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
    for %%b in (%%a) do (
    set string=%%b
    set "string=!string:[=,!"
    set "string=!string:]=,!" 
    echo !string!>>replaced.txt
    )
)
for /f "delims=" %%c in (replaced.txt) do (
    for %%d in (%%c) do (
    echo %%~d>>echo.txt
    )
)
for /f %%e in (echo.txt) do echo curl %%~e/pgn|find ".">>list.txt
```

I basically run 3 sets of loops, the first one loads my input (this could not be done via `set` because there's a size limit, using a nested loop works around that) and replaces `[` and `]` for commas.

The second loop sorts again the output. This is done basically to trim unwanted characters from the first and last line.

The last loop generates a list of curl commands that will later be executed into a PGN file (which is a chess file).

---

This ends the scope of the question, but since my project wasn't that complex, I'll present it's final version, which improves on Compo's answer, in case someone else stumbles upon this question:

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::             Chess.com and Lichess API Scraper               ::
::                  Author: fabiorzfreitas                     ::
:: Extract all games from a player from Chess.com and Lichess  ::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: This tool uses Chess.com and Lichess APIs to extract all games from a given player. ::

@echo off
setLocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo.
echo.
echo.
echo All input must be lowcase!
echo.
echo You can skip the input bellow by pressing Enter
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p lichess="Input Lichess nickname and press Enter: "
set /p chess="Input Chess.com nickname and press Enter: "
echo.

:Lichess
if not defined lichess goto :Chess

curl https://lichess.org/api/games/user/%lichess% >> Games.pgn

:Chess
if not defined chess goto :End

(for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=[]" %%g in (`curl https://api.chess.com/pub/player/%chess%/games/archives`) do (
    for %%h In (%%g) do curl "%%~h/pgn" >> Games.pgn
    )
)

:End
exit
```